# Remainder and quotient of polynomial division in $\mathbb Z_7[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

Find the quotient and remainder of:

$$ \frac {x^4 + [3]x^3 + [5]x} {x^2 + [2]} ; \mathbb Z_7[x]$$

Would the answer be the same if  it wasn't in  $\mathbb Z_7[x]$.  Namely:
Quotient: $x^2 +[3]x - [2]$
Remainder: $[-1]x+[4], or, [6]x + [4]? $

Comment: The two remainders you correctly offer are one and the same. Your quotient is right, too.